# Scraping content of webpage using Web-harvest

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, webharvest

I want to scrape particular contents from webpages, for this I am using web harvest.  It is working well for other website when I tried to scrape contents but it is not scraping contents for [this URL](http://freesearch.naukri.com/preview/preview?uname=63017692f2b266780bfd20476cd67466001a4a17005b4a5355041f121b502e18514b4e4e43121c4151005&sid=73682841&LT=1339495252).

My Java code is here:

```
import org.webharvest.definition.ScraperConfiguration;
import org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper;
import org.webharvest.runtime.variables.Variable;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class App 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try 
    {
        ScraperConfiguration config  =  new ScraperConfiguration("twit88.xml");
        Scraper scraper = new Scraper(config, "c:/temp/");
        //scraper.getHttpClientManager().setHttpProxy("proxy-server", 8001);
        scraper.addVariableToContext("url", "http://freesearch.naukri.com/preview/preview?uname=63017692f2b266780bfd20476cd67466001a4a17005b4a5355041f121b502e18514b4e4e43121c4151005&sid=73682841&LT=1339495252");
        scraper.setDebug(true);
        scraper.execute();
        // takes variable created during execution
        Variable article = (Variable)scraper.getContext().getVar("article");
        // do something with articles...
        System.out.println(article.toString());
        //System.out.println("1234=====rtyu");
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

And My XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config charset="UTF-8">
<!--
<var-def name="url">http://twit88.com/blog/2008/01/02/java-encrypt-and-send-a-   large-file-securely/</var-def>        
 -->

 <!-- <file action="write" path="twit88/twit88${sys.date()}.xml" charset="UTF-8"> -->

    <!--
    <template>
        <![CDATA[ <twit88 date="${sys.datetime("dd.MM.yyyy")}"> ]]>
    </template>
    -->
<var-def name="article">
    <xquery>
      <xq-param name="doc">
            <html-to-xml outputtype="browser-compact" prunetags="yes">
                <http url="${url}"/>
            </html-to-xml>
      </xq-param> 

      <xq-expression><![CDATA[ 
        declare variable $doc as node() external;          
         let $title := data($doc//div[@class="bdrGry"]/div[@class="boxHD1"]/h1)

        return
           <article>                
                 <title>{data($title)}</title>
           </article>             
       ]]>
       </xq-expression> 

    </xquery> 
    </var-def>
    <!--
      <![CDATA[ </twit88> ]]>  -->
    <!-- </file> -->               

     </config>
```

I want to scrape first block of this URL e.g candidate name, current designation, company etc., but I am unable to scrape by using its class in XML file e.g. (I tried only one for first attempt to scrape candidate name only)

```
  declare variable $doc as node() external;          
         let $title := data($doc//div[@class="bdrGry"]/div[@class="boxHD1"]/h1)
```

But it's not working.  Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, it is 'scrape' or 'scraping', as opposed to 'scrap' scraps' or 'scrapping'.  You might have picked up some hints from the code seen above.

Comment: thanks for correct me.But what is the solution of this?

Comment: The spelling?  An edit (which I've already done). That and paying more attention/using more care in typing questions in future.

Answer (score 3):

> ..it is not scraping contents for [this URL](http://freesearch.naukri.com/preview/preview?uname=63017692f2b266780bfd20476cd67466001a4a17005b4a5355041f121b502e18514b4e4e43121c4151005&sid=73682841&LT=1339495252).

From the [Terms & Conditions](http://jobsearch.naukri.com/mynaukri/mn_termsconditions.php) of Naukri.com:

> Naukri.com uses technological means to exclude Robots etc from crawling the website and **scraping content.** The user undertakes ***not to circumvent these methods.***